# Conditionally apply css class based on key value pair in a array, VueJS

Tags: css, arrays, vue.js, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have an array as shown in below picture. How do I add conditional CSS class to

based on the key `sender_id` of the array in VueJS ?

conditions:
1)if `sender_id != sender_id` : add arrived class
2)if `sender_id == sender_id`  : add delivered class.

The goal is to add CSS styling as per the arrived or delivered message in a chat application.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div v-bind:class="{ 'myClass1': sender_id === sender_id, 'myClass2': sender_id !== sender_id }" class="otherClass"></div>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Answer (score 1):

Use ternary operation:

```
<span :class="todo.sender_id === sender_id ? 'delivered' : 'arrived'">{{message}}</span>
```

[Check a sample fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/sharitu/0zdubh4n/1/)